# Can the PAM/SLM model be used to explain French speakers' perceptual issues with /h/?

Tags: second-lang-acquisition

Basically what it says in the title. I'm writing about the perceptual difficulties that French speakers have with /h/, and it seems that the main works for this phenomenon are Paradis & LaCharité 2001 amongst some others but PAM/PAM-L2/SLM aren't mentioned anywhere which surprises me. Is it because it's a matter of /h/ VS / Ø / rather than /h/ VS, for example, / ħ /?

(for context, in French, words that begin with /h/ orthographically aren't pronounced with an /h/ at the beginning - it's dropped. This obviously leads to transfer in that a lot of beginners don't even perceive the /h/ as being there.)

Comment: This question may also be a good fit for [languagelearning.se]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that it is an interference of *written French*: Just because native speakers of French are used to read an ⟨h⟩ as  /Ø/ they transfer this habit to other languages.

Teaching a foreign language to French speakers primarily via spoken language and not providing the writing for a longer time may result in different results.